# Getting 'Number of times' an application is used/opened

Tags: android

Is it possible to get count for,

- **How many times a third party application has run so far.**.? (It can be number of times after boot or number of times after user installed it).

Actually, I am showing a list of application for user to choose which application they want to install first. Requirement is to show the list in sorted order. Order should be where 'least used application' is shown first & most used application is shown at last.

I have seen some of the stuff mentioned in Greenify application, but then again that application requires root access which can also meant that 'this' information is available only if you have a root access.

Hope the my query makes sense.

Comment: It is not possible without root access. Letting 3rd party applications know what apps you are using would be a severe breach of privacy.

Comment: Not sure if it's becuase of privacy cause if I can control user's call, sms.... allowing the access count of any app is least in security check list. Do you have any link ( by any chance) which mentions the saem?

Comment: Do you tried to dial *#*#4636#*#* and there will be statics/freq. if you can find related source code, maybe you can look into it.